# Word 2013 Copying Images Shows Blank Square

Tags: microsoft-word, images

Recently, copying and pasting images from the Internet into my Word or Outlook document/e-mail stopped working.

Instead of showing the actual image, it inserts a white square. This is how it looks (yes, there is an image below):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y4F4.jpg]

Note that other pictures are displayed properly. I'm NOT using the option to replace all images with white squares and black lines around them:

[image: http://imgsrv.worldstart.net/images/ct-images/2012/02/word_pic_placeholder_option.jpg]

A workaround would be saving the image to the disk and then dragging and dropping the file from the explorer into Word. I do not want that since it unnecessarily wastes my time.

Can you tell me why this is happening and how I can make it stop?

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you log into the computer as a different user?  How about if you try it while booted in Safe Mode?

Comment: I'm the only user (administrator) and if I boot Windows in Safe Mode it won't recognize my Office license and refuses the run the application. In case you meant the Word Safe Mode using `winword /safe` command, the issue persists

Comment: Create a new user and try with that one.  I'm trying to help you narrow it down to whether its a system-wide problem, or just something about your user account.  I did mean Windows' Safe Mode, but knowing you tried `winword /safe` helps too. :)  Exactly which version of Office/Word 2013 are you using?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: On a new user account it works fine, the image can be pasted normally. The version is `Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013`. How do I reset it? Deleting the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word` did not work, just like deleting the `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates` folder.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue in **Word 2016**, I found **Paste Special (Alt + Ctrl + V)**.
This lets you choose to paste as **Bitmap**.